# How to divide linear layout into four equal parts?

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I want to give the Textview 3/4 of the linear layout and the imagebutton view 1/4. But It doesn't work as intended but if I make four buttons it will divide it equally.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:background="@color/dark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/txtresult"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/del"
        android:text="@string/del"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change the `<TextView>`'s and `<ImageView>`'s `layout_width`s to `0dp`. Also, the `layout_weight` on the `<LinearLayout>` isn't necessary, unless it's actually being weighted itself inside another `<LinearLayout>`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "layout_weight" from "LinearLayout" Tag its work for me.

Here is code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/txtresult"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/del"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

first Remove the `android:layout_weight="1"` from LinearLayout. then set `android:layout_width="0dp"` for TextView & ImageButton. and then set `android:layout_weight="0.75"` for TextView and set `android:layout_weight="0.25"` for ImageButton .

like this :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:background="@color/dark"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.75"
    android:id="@+id/txtresult"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="50sp"/>
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/del"
    android:text="@string/del"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</LinearLayout>
```